# Qt linker errors Qmake + Makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, linker-errors, qmake

I want to build a Qt project outside Qt Creator, so I'm using qmake to generate a Makefile on the following project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += . \
               /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --std=c++11

# Input
SOURCES += test.cc
```

Which was generated also by qmake, bar the c++11 flag and the second include path. The Makefile contains link paths to the Qt library

```
LIBS = $(SUBLIBS) -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5Gui -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Core -lG L -lpthread
```

What's weird in the above is that I don't have a `/usr/X11R6` folder. Instead, `libQt5Gui.so` is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so I'm a little puzzled where the X11R6 comes from.

Anyway, this is my linker output:

```
test.cc:(.text.startup+0x20): undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
test.cc:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
test.cc:(.text.startup+0x2f): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
test.cc:(.text.startup+0x43): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
```

The above is the result of building the following source:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I try to build the project file in Qt Creator, the same error appears. Am I missing libraries? Or is something configured erroneously?

(I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and I just installed the `qtcreator` package from the repo's, assuming that all development libraries would be installed along with it.)

Comment: You also might want to replace `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --std=c++11` with `CONFIG += c++11` to let Qt/qmake know that you are using C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html), you need to include the widget library to use `QApplication`.

Add this to your project file:

```
QT += widgets
```

If you're not going to build a GUI app, use [`QCoreApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html) instead. It doesn't have that dependency.

Comment: Jeez, I knew it was going to be a simple fix, but this makes me feel a little bad for even asking. Funny how this didn't show up anywhere in all my search efforts. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Don't feel too bad. Your problem was a bit obfuscated by you adding the Qt include path directly. Without it you would have gotten something like 'QApplication: No such file or directory'. Plenty of answers for this question :-)